# Javascript calling HTTP on a SSL Site

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

my question is simple, I am mounting a website about Overwatch Boosting, got an SSL, however seems like there's a JS calling the original theme website for an image from them instead of using my own https server.
[image: Security Error]

I would like to know how do i get rid of this or those javascript calling a non HTTPS request, so i can get my website fully secure.

My website is this one incase you need more info -> www.boostingkings.com

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems here. SSL relies on ALL connections being secure. If you are getting the theme through HTTP, you might as well not have SSL at all.

In your source code, make sure you specify HTTPS. Here are some examples of what to do:

```
<img src="https://example.com/themes/theme.css" />
<img src="//example.com/themes/theme.css" />
<img src="/themes/theme.css" />
```

This is not safe:

```
<img src="http://example.com/themes/theme.css" />
```

In addition, it's not usually a good idea to use JS to call external resources. Try using pre fetching.

Comment: Thats not what im asking about, im saying there's a hook in some JS script i think? That is calling an external website but i can't really see where it is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the code your using? We're not psychics. Developer tools may be able to solve your problem, but ultimately, you need to know what you're code does.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the problem, and also the website where is problem is.